# How to get the number of likes of a picture on Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

I want to get the number of likes of a picture in Facebook, and show it on my websites.

I managed to find out the FQL query for it:

```
SELECT like_info FROM photo WHERE object_id=10152003701188306
```

When I tried that query at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer, I get `like_count = 792`.

I have every Facebook connect setting up and working (app id + secret key). I've checked the debugger of my URL, and it has all meta tags needed.

I managed to write this code, but it gives me an empty result instead of a number.

```
$result = $facebook->api(array(         
          'method' => 'fql.query',   
          'query' => 'SELECT like_info FROM photo WHERE object_id=10152003701188306'  
      ));  
echo $result['like_count'];
```

How can I make it work properly?

Answer (score 0):

The array returned by FQL is pretty big and complex. You need:

```
echo $result['data']['like_info']['like_count'];
```

To see everything that comes back in your query use this code:

```
printf('<pre>%s</pre', print_r($result,TRUE) );
```